# Perl Image::Magic Watermark Error

Tags: perl, imagemagick, cgi

I'm trying to add a watermark to a image using Image::Magic, bot I keep on getting this error

```
Can't call method "Read" on an undefined value at ImageUploader.pl line xxx.
```

Witch is:

```
$Logo->Read('../Data/Images/Watermark.png');
```

in the code below and can not figure it out the path is right and the file exists.

Any ideas?

```
use Image::Magick;

my $NewImage = Image::Magick->new;
$NewImage->Read("../Data/Temp/Images/$SaveAs$Extension");

my ($Width,$Height) = $NewImage->Get('width','height'); # find dimensions

my $ResizedWidth = 275;
my $ResizedHeight = 450;

my $MeduimThumbnailWidth = 300;
my $MeduimThumbnailHeight = 300;


if($Height >= $ResizedHeight){
my $ResizedHeight = int($Height * ($ResizedWidth / $Width));

$Logo->Read('../Data/Images/Watermark.png');
$NewImage->Composite(compose=>'blend', blend=>'50x50', x=>'50', y=>'50', image=>$Logo,);

$NewImage->Resize(width=>$ResizedWidth, height=>$ResizedHeight);
$NewImage->Write("../Data/Images/$URL/$SaveAs\_lrg$Extension");
}else{
$NewImage->Write("../Data/Images/$URL/$SaveAs\_lrg$Extension");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$Logo` is undefined because you never assign a value to it.

Presumably you are missing:

```
my $Logo = Image::Magick->new();
```

You are also missing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

… which should appear in all modern Perl programmes.